# OpenGL: Should i always clip the glColor*f values myself?

Tags: c++, opengl, colors

This may sound stupid... but I've been wondering, does it matter if i send a value greater than 1.0f to the glColor*f functions?

Does older gfx cards/drivers handle these differently? Does OpenGL directly use the color value i give to it, or does it clip it on its own? Should i stop doing if(r > 1.0f) r = 1.0f; ? Is there any danger the greater than 1.0f would result in unexpeceted behaviour?

I cant seem to get greater than 1.0f to do anything different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glcolor3f):

"Neither floating-point nor signed integer values are clamped to the range [0,1] before the current color is updated. However, color components are clamped to this range before they are interpolated or written into a color buffer."

Comment: So, values greater than 1.0 will be indistinguishable in effect from 1.0 if you have some sort of straight-through path to the framebuffer; if you have any arithmetic going on (such as with lighting and glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)) then the outputs may be different.

Comment: In other words, you should clamp them.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL will clamp the values to the [0, 1] range automatically.